# How to invoke native function in Java code

Tags: android, java-native-interface, native

I have found some android native method is very useful to me.

```
private native void nativeMoveSelection(int x, int y);
```

This method is invoked by android.webkit.WebKit.java. And i change my package to android.webkit. but when i call this method , the system will throw java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError.

Comment: Please post the complete exception message and stack trace. Your question is too vague to be answered in its present form.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you dont have the required .so library in your application. For using native functions u need to load the native library (.so) file using `System.loadlibrary("yourLibrary")`.

Comment: nativeMoveSelection is exported by libwebcore.so. I already have loaded that library.

Comment: I`d like to know if it is possible to use the system library or native function?